# Display number of Product in "My Cart" in header - Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I want to display number of products as "My Cart" in Header in magento. act i found some code as 
`

```
 $count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
 $total = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
 if($count==0)
 {
     echo "0";
 }
 if($count==1)
 {
     echo $this->__('%s',$count);
 }
 if($count>1)
 {
     echo $this->__('%s',$count);
 }
```

and used it in Top.phtml.

Act its working fine. But issue is that, to display the correct data(total number of product in a cart) every time i have to delete the Cache. I just want, it should not be depended on cache, like in magento how it changing the count on the side bar just like that it should change on header also, should not be dependend on Cache. I am using, Magento 1.4.1. Its very urgent, if any one can help.. Thankz in Advance Friendz..

Comment: This function is existing in 1.9.3.8. Consider updating your Magento version I guess.

Answer (score 2):

1.goto app->code->core->mage->checkout->block->links.php

2.edit the code like below

$count=Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();`

if($count>=1)
{

$text=$this->__('Mycart(%s items)',$count);

}

else

{

$text=$this->__('Mycart');

}

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I never actually had cache problems with this (although i am on 1.5.0.0 here), could you try `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems()->count()` ?

Answer (score 0):

**For Display number of products in the cart**

```
<?php
  $count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();  //get total items in cart
  $total = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); //get total price
  if($count==0)
  {
    echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(0 ITEMS)</a>',$count);
  }
  if($count==1)
  {
    echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(1 ITEM)</a>',$count);
  }
  if($count>1)
  {
    echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(%s ITMES)</a>',$count);
  }
  echo $this->__('', $this->helper('core')->formatPrice($total, false));
?>
```